# macOs bash/terminal command to open terminal, change directory and run command

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I am writing what I assume is pretty easy bash script file. Although I cannot seem to do the following combination:

> open new terminal instance > cd to directory > run command in that terminal instance

I got as far as:

`open -b com.apple.terminal /path/I/want/`

but if I try something like:

`open -b com.apple.terminal /path/I/want/ && /path/to/command someCommand`

It runs in the original window instance and not the new one. Tried some other variations of that as well with no success

Comment: I would suggest looking at the man page for terminal:  "man terminal"  What you are looking for may be a command line option that terminal has to run a command after starting.  Other similar unix commands (like xterm) use -e 'my-command'. To run a command in another window you need the command itself to allow it.  If you try and attach to standard input for the window, it will terminate when stdin runs out.

Comment: The command you want to run should not be directed to the terminal program but to the shell, bash.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this with the following:

`osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd /directory/to/open && /path/to/command command\""`

Comment: You could execute a shell script with `open -b com.apple.terminal ./gash.sh`

Comment: That is similar to what I had before just without the ability to change to the directory I wanted it to be executed in.

Comment: Just put a `cd` into the shell script